# Codeigniter session not working with my code

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, session

I have this problem with this session in codeigniter that nothing displays. I use to call the result with an ajax. If I direct it to echo only it shows the correct user id. I don't know were do I wrong? I hope someone will correct me. Thank you

This is my function for user login. This is for setting a session for the current user login

```
public function login(){

    $username = $this->input->post('username');
    $password = $this->input->post('password');

        $sql= $this->crud->getData("
                tbl_user","
                user_username='$username' AND 
                user_password=md5('$password')
                LIMIT 1");

     if($sql['total']==1) { 

            $user_sess = array();

                 foreach($sql['rows'] as $row){
                     $user_sess = array('user_id'=>$row->user_id,
                                       'user_name'=>$row->user_username,
                                       'user_role'=>$row->user_role,
                                       'profile_id'=>$row->profile_id,
                                       'user_type'=>$row->user_type,
                                       'user_status'=>$row->user_status,
                                       'user_group_id'=>$row->user_group_id,
                                       'user_sub_group_id'=>$row->user_sub_group_id);
                 }            

            $this->session->set_userdata('user_sess', $user_sess); 

            $result['login']='valid';
       }else{

            $result['login']='invalid';

    }//end if else

    echo json_encode($result);

}/*END LOGIN FUNCTION*/
```

This is the function were the session is not working. Calling current user login id

```
function user_current_details(){

$user_id=$this->session->userdata('user_sess');


$sql = $this->crud->getData("tbl_user as u,tbl_group as g, tbl_sub_group as sg, tbl_user_permission as up, tbl_user_profile as p", "u.user_id= '$user_id[user_id]' AND u.user_group_id=g.group_id AND u.user_sub_group_id = sg.sub_group_id AND up.user_user_perm ='$user_id[user_id]' AND u.profile_id=p.profile_id")['rows'];

echo json_encode($sql);
```

}

And this is the Ajax function to display in the View. With this example I call the user profile picture to be display in the view.

```
function user_current_details(){

$.post(baseurl + 'globalFunction/user_current_details', {

}, function (data) {
    var result = eval('(' + data + ')');
    $("#img_user_current").attr('src',baseurl+'files/user_pics/'+result[0].profile_img);
})}
```

Thank you. Sorry for my bad english

Comment: Anyone there .. please.. :(

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html refer this to see if there is any sort of error...

Comment: and one more thing, if you have limited the number of results to 1 that means only one value would be there. In this case why do you need foreach?

Comment: public function signup()
 {
  
  $data = array(
   'signupFName' => $this->input->post('signupFName'),
   'signupLName' => $this->input->post('signupLName'),
   'signupEmail' => $this->input->post('signupEmail'),
   'signupPassword' => $this->input->post('signupPassword')
  );
  
  $this->session->set_userdata('user_signup', $data);} something like this should be enough

Comment: another thing...... modularity is not present in your code. I see model operations present in the controller, this would certainly create a mess....correct that too

Answer (score 0):

The array is which you are defining session data, the user ID is set as `user_id`

So, in the `user_current_details()` function, you would get the user ID like this:

```
$user_id=$this->session->userdata('user_id');
```

instead of

```
$user_id=$this->session->userdata('user_sess');
```

Read the documentation for more help: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#retrieving-session-data